# Loopback MongoDB connector-specific configuration

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to build a simple rest api using Strongloop. I have installed mongoDB in my machine. When I try to set the datasource of my api it asks for Connector-specific configuration:

> ? Connection String url to override other settings (eg:
>   mongodb://username:passw ord@hostname:port/database):

What should I go from here? I guess my host is localhost, port is 27017, with no specific username & password.

This is what I'm trying to do:
http://onehungrymind.com/build-simple-rest-app-angularjs-part-1-node-api-strongloop/

and here I got stuck:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your file `package.json` is not allowing **write** permission.
Try this out on terminal

`$ sudo chown -R tanvir:tanvir /home/tanvir/simple-rest-api/package.json`

Now run again the loopback datasource adding mongodb.